# GWT DefaultRequestTransport - inserting request parameter

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm implimenting a token based CSRF prevention system in my GWT Request Factory based app. At the moment I'm overriding the `send(String, TransportReceiver)`  method on DefaultRequestTransport to insert a custom header into the request.

This works fine, but I want to modify it to insert the token into the body of the request because my app might be deployed behind firewalls which could strip the custom header.

Inserting the header is easy using RequestBuilder.setHeader(), but there doesn't seem to be a correspondingly easy way to insert parameters in the request body.

Do I really have to manipulate the payload string manually, or is there an easier way?